# Flow component : Delete Records

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, dml, delete

I have a Screen Flow. There is one Screen Element containing a Lightning Web Component which is based on the standard lightning-datatable component, which allows the user to edit a set of records. These records are SObjects.

The LWC has three output properties of type `@salesforce/schema/xx__Seniority__c[]`:

- `deletedSeniorityList` containing records to be deleted
- `updatedSeniorityList` containing records to be updated
- `newSeniorityList` - containing records to be inserted

All thee of these lists are being correctly set by the LWC according to the user's edits to the table.

All three are then copied into flow record collection variables (`SenioritiesToDelete`, `SenioritiesToInsert` & `SenioritiesToUpdate`) for the appropriate SObject type.

When I debug the flow and make no changes to the table, the following debug details appear, which seem to be correct:

```
Outputs:
deletedSeniorityList = SenioritiesToDelete ([])
newSeniorityList = SenioritiesToInsert ([])
updatedSeniorityList = SenioritiesToUpdate ([])
```

(all empty, as expected, because no edits were made)

After the screen lement, there are theee more elements to perform the DML: Delete Records, Update Records, Create Records, each using the appropriate records collection variable.

The Delete Records operation fails with the following error:

**DELETE RECORDS**: Delete_Seniorities
Delete xx__Seniority__c records whose IDs are stored in {!SenioritiesToDelete}.

**Variable Values**

None.

**Result**

Failed to delete records whose IDs are in {!SenioritiesToDelete}.

Error Occurred: No records in Salesforce match your delete criteria.

Why would this error occur if the list of records to delete is empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is now a [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001uu8OQAQ) for this you can follow. For now, you'll have to have a decision element to check for an empty collection before proceeding with the delete element.

Create and Update elements behave as expected, with no operation being performed if the collection is empty.

Comment: Jan 2024 (well Feb in some locations right now) and not fixed so have to add another query.  Oh my.